# Having Capistrano skip over down hosts

Tags: deployment, error-handling, capistrano

### My setup

I am deploying a Ruby on Rails application to 70+ hosts. These hosts are located behind consumer-grade ADSL connections which may or may not be up. Probability of being up is aroud 99% but definently not 100%.

The deploy process works perfectly fine and I have no problem specific to it.

### The problem

When Capistrano encounters a down host, it stops the entire process. This is a problem because if host n°30 is down, then the 40 other hosts after it do not get the deployment.

What I would like is definently an error for the hosts that are down but I would also like Capistrano to continue deploying to all the hosts that are up.

Is there any setting or configuration that would enable me to do this ?

Comment: You probably need to monkey patch Capistrano itself to allow process to continue when connection can not be established. This should not be long when you read all the Capistrano sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running a Capistrano instance for each IP then parsing the logs to see which one has failed and which one has succeeded.

A little Python script adjusted to my needs does this fine.